# How to add vertical alignment feature to a major-mode for Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, vertical-alignment, system-verilog

I am using verilg-mode for emacs everyday but the code alignment is not that good for me. So want to add something like vertical alignment.

First, I hope to align the declaration lines like these:

```
bit [1:0] a;
bit [3254:0] b;
bit unsigned [P_DWIDTH-1:0] c;
bit unsigned [P_DWIDTH-1:P_DWIDTH-4] d;
int e;
```

to:

```
bit          [         1:0         ] a;
bit          [      3254:0         ] b;
bit unsigned [P_DWIDTH-1:0         ] c;
bit unsigned [P_DWIDTH-1:P_DWIDTH-4] d;
int                                  e;
```

I don't have much Elisp experience. I am not sure something like `align-regexp` is the right thing to look at? Or anyone please point me a right direction to start.

Comment: You could also have asked on the Emacs StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @homeless reply, I did modification: Use `narrow-to-region` to avoid region boundary changes.

```
(defun align-decl-vertically ()
  "Align verilog declarations."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      ;; remove spaces around ":"
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\s-*:\\s-*" (point-max) t)
        (replace-match ":"))

      ;; align "["
      (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\[" -1 1 0)
      ;; align ":"
      (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max) "\\[\\(.+:\\)" -1 0 0)
      ;; align "]"
      (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max) "\\s-*\\(\\]\\)" -1 0 0)
      ;; align variable name
      (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max) "\\(\\s-+\\)\\S-+;" -1 1 0)
      (widen))))
```

Also find another way to update rules for `align` to achieve this (this not work exactly as what I expect but just list here maybe some would help me to fix it):

```
(add-to-list 'align-mode-rules-list                             
             '(declaration-range-field-alignment                 
               (regexp . "\\(\\s-*\\[\\)\\(.*:\\).*\\S-+\\(\\s-*\\]\\)\\(.*\\)")
               (group . (1 2 3 4))                              
               (modes . '(verilog-mode))                        
               (tab-stop . nil)                                 
               (spacing . (1 0 0 1))                            
               (repeat . nil)                                   
               (justify . t)))                                  
(add-to-list 'align-mode-rules-list                             
             '(declaration-variable-name-alignment              
               (regexp . "\\(\\s-*\\S-*\\s-*;\\)")                  
               (group . 1)                                      
               (modes . '(verilog-mode))                        
               (repeat . nil)                                   
               (tab-stop . nil)                                 
               (spacing . 1)                                    
               (justify . t)))
```

But sometimes it may need to run `align` more than once to get the final result. I haven't figure out why yet.

Answer (score 2):

You could try indeed with `align-regexp`. Does the following help you:

```lisp
(defun align-decl-vertically ()
  "Align verilog declarations."
  (interactive)
  (let ((BEG (region-beginning))
        (END (region-end)))
    (align-regexp BEG END "\\(\\s-*\\)\\[" 1 1 0)
    (align-regexp BEG END "\\(\\s-*\\)\\]" 1 1 0)
    (align-regexp BEG END "\\(\\s-*\\)\\s-[^ ]*;" 1 0 0)))

;; declare a key binding
(add-hook 'verilg-mode-hook (lambda() (local-set-key (kbd "C-c =") 'align-decl-vertically)))
```

You have to paste it into your Emacs init file (e.g. .emacs or init.el). Once you are in `verilog-mode`, you can highlight the region and press `C-c =` to align the declarations. I tested it with your example and it worked out. I do not know if it is going to work in the general case as I am not aware of the verilog programming syntax.

**UPDATE**

The first version does not work correctly for the simple reason that we shouldn't save the beginning and ending of a region in variables as they change after each `align-regexp` call. Here comes a version which should work:

```lisp
(defun align-decl-vertically ()
  "Align verilog declarations."
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\[" 1 1 0)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\]" 1 1 0)
  (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\s-[^ ]*;" 1 0 0))
```

Comment: Thanks @homeless. But your code doesn't work for the last line alignment. I did a little modification and will put it in another answer.

Comment: I just figured out why it did not work. I actually posted a modified version here. I will update my answer and now it should work just fine with one call.